# The iso message is sent incomplete jpos

Tags: java, iso8583, jpos, iso8583-1993

Sending the iso message is sent incomplete, I don't know why

in this way I am sending it

```
// Create Packager based on XML that contain DE type
        GenericPackager packager = new GenericPackager("PackISO.xml");

        // Crea una instancia de la clase BASE24TCPChannel
       BASE24TCPChannel c = new BASE24TCPChannel("localhost", 5000,packager);
       c.setHeader("ISO008000099");
       
        // Create ISO Message
        ISOMsg isoMsg = new ISOMsg();
        
        isoMsg.setPackager(packager);
 
        isoMsg.setMTI("0800");
        isoMsg.set(7, "1088110140");
        isoMsg.set(11, "087478");
        isoMsg.set(70, "999");

        c.connect();
        c.send(isoMsg);
```

this is what is sent:

```
00000000: 0044 4953 4f30 3038 3030 3030 3939 3038  .DISO00800009908
00000010: 3030 3832 3230 3030 3030 3030 3030 3030  0082200000000000
00000020: 3030 3034 3030 3030 3030 3030 3030 3030  0004000000000000
00000030: 3030 3130 3838 3131 3031 3430 3038 3734  0010881101400874
```

But if I add another connection to the shipment, if it arrives complete, because this behavior helps, I'm new to JPOS.

```
    // Create Packager based on XML that contain DE type
        GenericPackager packager = new GenericPackager("PackISO.xml");

        // Crea una instancia de la clase BASE24TCPChannel
       BASE24TCPChannel c = new BASE24TCPChannel("localhost", 5000,packager);
       c.setHeader("ISO008000099");
       
        // Create ISO Message
        ISOMsg isoMsg = new ISOMsg();
        
        isoMsg.setPackager(packager);
 
        isoMsg.setMTI("0800");
        isoMsg.set(7, "1088110140");
        isoMsg.set(11, "087478");
        isoMsg.set(70, "999");

        c.connect();
        c.send(isoMsg);
        
        
        c.connect();
```

here if it arrives complete when connecting twice

```
00000000: 0044 4953 4f30 3038 3030 3030 3939 3038  .DISO00800009908
00000010: 3030 3832 3230 3030 3030 3030 3030 3030  0082200000000000
00000020: 3030 3034 3030 3030 3030 3030 3030 3030  0004000000000000
00000030: 3030 3130 3838 3131 3031 3430 3038 3734  0010881101400874
00000040: 3738 3939 3903                           78999.
```

how can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be a problem with the message being sent incomplete.

It looks more like a thing on how you are visualizing things, if you are trying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76485890/3444205) the thing is `xxd` is expecting the next line. It will show the entire message after the other side disconnects and netcat finishes.